# Positioning Marker head point out to the Polyline path

Tags: android

I want to position the marker head point out to the polyline path starting position and the polyline drawn between source and destination marker.
My code snippet is

```
list=polyline1.getPoints();
list.add(latlng_value);
now= googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(list.get(0)) //points = the List of LatLngpoint
                    .draggable(false)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow_up)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the logic if you want to put markers on your polyline

- First, to draw a `polyline`, you need a list of `LatLng point` that define the polyline nodes.
- To put the "Source" marker, set its position on the first `LatLng point`
- To put the "Destination" marker, set its position on the last `LatLngPoint`

A little code snippet for the marker

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(points.get(0)) //points = the List of LatLng point
            .draggable(false)
            .title(getString(R.string.label_start).toUpperCase()) // Text you want to add as title
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_start))); // Custom icon for marker
```

**EDIT**

Here's what I would do :

**Declare the Points list**

```
list=polyline1.getPoints();
```

**Add the source marker**

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(list.get(0))
    .draggable(false)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow_up)));
```

**Add the destination marker**

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(list.get(list.size()-1))
    .draggable(false)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow_up)));
```

**Draw polyline**

```
googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .addAll(list);
```

Comment: I got list of LatLng points from  this code list=line1.getPoints();// list as LatLng List
              list.add(latlng);
            now=  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(list.get(0)) //points = the List of LatLng point
              .draggable(false)
               // Text you want to add as title
              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow_up))); //now is marker

Comment: I already drawn the polyline between source and destination and i want to rotate the marker head and it point out to the destination marker direction.

Comment: Use the destination marker code I wrote on my answer for your source marker head.